# Postfix: Local and virtual mailboxes

Tags: postfix

I want to set up my postfix with two kinds of recipients:

1. Some have a UNIX Account
2. Some have a virtual mailbox

I have two configurations which are working for each scenario, but none for both:

I use Ubuntu 18.10 with Postfix only.

This is the content of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, working for scenario 1, comments work for scenario 2 (must be switched):

```
myhostname = server1.FQDN.TLD
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost, server1.FQDN.TLD, $myorigin #1
#2 mydestination = localhost, server1.FQDN.TLD
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases #1
#2 virtual_mailbox_domains = FQDN.TLD
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

My `/etc/postfix/aliases`:

```
info@FQDN.TLD  user
postmaster@FQDN.TLD user
```

And finally `/etc/postfix/vmailbox`:

```
theodor@FQDN.TLD FQDN.TLD/theodor/
sales@FQDN.TLD FQDN.TLD/sales/
erik@FQDN.TLD  FQDN.TLD/erik/
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: When I add the virtual mailboxes all addresses are treated as virtual and none as local. The documentation says otherwise.

Comment: I'll bet it isn't "all", just "all addresses `@FQDN.TLD`", which is entirely in line with the documentation.  If that isn't the case, relevant exerpts from the mail logs would be useful to demonstrate your assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use `postmap vmailbox`, so it used the following content:

```
theodor@FQDN.TLD FQDN.TLD/theodor/
sales@FQDN.TLD FQDN.TLD/sales/
erik@FQDN.TLD  FQDN.TLD/erik/
postmaster  FQDN.TLD/user/
```

Postfix tried to resolve the previously configured mailbox in /var/mail/vhosts/FQDN/user in addition to the user on my system and got confused.